# Inject secret to Docker image via Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline in Azure Devops building and pushing some images to DockerHub. These images are pushed to a production and development environment, but are also available for pulling for local development. For secrets in production and development in Azure we just use keystore and variable groups. However, we haven't found a good solution for injecting secrets when working locally.

For instance, in appsettings.json we have a ClientSecret parameter that is used for authenticating against Azure AD. How can we insert this parameter into appsettings.json during the release pipeline and not have it be visible to someone else later?

Some suggestions include using file transform in the pipeline, but this is not optimal as we don't really want to change any files. Another suggestion is using --build-arg in the pipeline, but these arguments become visible with `docker history`.

So how can I inject a secret into appsettings.json in a Docker image, and this secret should preferably not be visible anywhere at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned, with using [File transforms a=nd variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops) is a less configuration and quick approach.

Besides, you could also choose to use **Azure Key Vault**.

> Azure Key Vault helps teams to securely store and manage sensitive
>   information such as keys, password, certificates, etc. in a
>   centralized storage which are safeguarded by industry-standard
>   algorithms, key lengths, and even hardware security modules. This
>   prevents information exposure through source code, a common mistake
>   that many developers make. Many developers leave sensitive information
>   such as database connection strings, passwords, private keys, etc. in
>   their source code which when gained by malicious users can result in
>   undesired consequences.
>
> Access to a key vault requires proper authentication and authorization
>   and with RBAC, teams can have even fine granular control who has what
>   permissions over the sensitive data.

As for how to use Azure Key Vault in Azure DevOps, you could kindly refer below blog:

- [How to inject Azure Key Vault secrets in the Azure DevOps CI/CD
  pipelines](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/How-to-inject-Azure-Key-Vault-secrets-in-the-Azure-DevOps-CICD-pipelines/)
- [Using secrets from Azure Key Vault in a pipeline](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurekeyvault/)

How to use docker image secret with Azure Key Vault, you could take a look at this link: [Publishing a Single Image Docker Container with Secrets from VS2017 and Running it on Azure](http://thedatafarm.com/docker/publishdockertoazure/)

More ways for your reference: [7 Ways to Deal with Application Secrets in Azure](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/7-ways-to-deal-with-application-secrets-in-azure/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lets say I use the replace token extension, inject a ConnectionString and build a Docker image and push this to DockerHub. Will it be possible for someone to view the ConnectionString in this image or will it be completely hidden?

Comment: @PalBo No, others will not able view the connection string info from deployed image. I also found another approach by using Kubernetes, kindly check it if you are interested: [DevOps Friday: Build a deployment pipeline using K8s secrets](https://strive2code.net/post/2018/12/07/devops-friday-build-a-deployment-pipeline-using-k8s-secrets)